# Accessing dynamically created Dojo datagrid by id

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid, dojo

I am new to Dojo and trying to complete a page with a set of dynamically created datagrids.

Each grid is created as follows :

```
    membersGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            query: { id: '*'},
            structure: membersLayout,
            store: membersStore,
            autoWidth: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            initialWidth: '650px',
            rowSelector: '5px',
            rowsPerPage: 20,
            selectable: true
            }, 'membersGridNode'+index.toString());
```

I have a dynamically created button under each grid that triggers a click event when pressed. From this event I am able to get my data grid index.

```
function performCopyAction (button) {

    var gridName = "membersGridNode"+button.id;
    var grid = dijit.byId(gridName);

...
```

From here on the idea is to get the object and get access to the selected row on the datagrid. However, "grid" is null. I have tried a plethora of ways to get the grid object from Google searching but I am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create and widgets/dijits dynamically or declaratively you need to specify the `id` attribute as shown below. If `id` attribute is not provided then the dojo dijit systems assigns a unique id.

```
membersGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    ....
    ....
```

then access the dijit anywhere as

```
 var grid = dijit.byId('grid');
```